# How to restart a Wix Managed Bootstrapper Application after a reboot?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have a Managed Bootstrapper Application written in Wix and I am having trouble handling reboots. So far I have an exe package with an exitcode

Also, In my Run Method I have

```
 if (this.Command.Resume == ResumeType.Reboot)
        {
            model.SetWindowHandle(view);
            this.Engine.Detect();
            //view.Show();
            Dispatcher.Run();
            //this.Engine.Quit(model.FinalResult);
        }
```

This is my ApplyComplete Event Handler

```
    protected void ApplyComplete(object sender, ApplyCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        this.model.FinalResult = e.Status;
        if (model.bootstrapperApplication.Command.Action == LaunchAction.Uninstall)
        {
            model.bootstrapperApplication.Engine.Quit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            BootstrapperApplication.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
            {
                BootstrapperApplication.view.Close();
            });

            BootstrapperApplication.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            e.Result = Result.Restart;
        }
    }
```

As of now, My bootstrapper installs the exe package and restarts the computer without showing any dialog box as to it being restarting. Also, After the computer restarts.. The managed bootstrapper does not launch by itself

How do I get the bootstrapper to launch after restarting?